# Spring Integration - Expired MessageGroups in an Aggregator are re-expired 3 times

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have an Aggregator with a discard-channel that we use to count discarded messages ( to trigger an opertation upon reaching a concrete number ).

But looking at the logs I see that **the MessageGroup gets expired 3 times** for each message group, and I dont understand why.

My expected behaviour was that when a message gets expired it's removed from the Aggregator and won't get introduced again in the route.

This is my Aggregator :

```
<int:aggregator id="aggregatorByBatchAndSku"
input-channel="productAggregatorChannel"
output-channel="productAggregatedChannel"
expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
release-strategy="mainAggregatorReleaseStrategy"
release-strategy-method="canRelease"
correlation-strategy-expression="headers[${rip.headers.batchno.name}]+headers[${rip.headers.skuid.name}]"
discard-channel="aggregatorDiscardChannel"
send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
group-timeout="${rip.config.aggregator.group_timeout}"
expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the root cause of that.

After the discard-channel used by the Aggregator, I had a Service Activator counting the messages, and then the output went to a another channel and the route ended there.

Activating the DEBUG mode I saw that the MessageGroup was re dispatched because no consumer was attached to that end channel.

```
2017-04-20 12:12:08.987 DEBUG 15272 --- [sk-scheduler-10] .s.i.a.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler : The MessageGroup [ 666110005888011] is rescheduled by the reason: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:test:-1.fakeChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
2017-04-20 12:12:08.987 DEBUG 15272 --- [sk-scheduler-10] .s.i.a.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler : Schedule MessageGroup [ SimpleMessageGroup{groupId=666110005888011, messages=[GenericMessage [payload=.....
```

**So, the solution was to have the ServiceActivator as a terminator element not returning any value.**

Comment: Hm. I don't like that situation. At least that must be logged under warn. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and will revise that behavior